# Modify link and node colours in Sankey with NetworkD3

Tags: javascript, r, d3.js, sankey-diagram, networkd3

I want to change the colours of the node and links in my Sankey. Unfortunately d3.scale.Ordinal() function doesn't work for me.
Do you have any idea?
Idealy, the Nodes on the left hand side should have the same colours as the links leaving these.

If you have any idea, I'd be very happy. The Sankey works without the colouring .
Thessie

Here is the code:

````
links2 <- data.frame(source=c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5),target=c(6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9),value=c(3,6,8,8,2,7,5,1,5,5,13,12,43,5,2,7,8,6,5,7,3,5,4,19))

nodes2 <-data.frame(name=c("Cow","Ice","Emu","Coala","Uhu","Panda","Pink","Cyan","Grey","Green"))          

links2$group <- as.factor(c("type_a","type_b","type_c","type_d","type_e","type_f"))

nodes2$group <- as.factor(c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"))

my_colour <- 'd3.scale.Ordinal().domain(["type_a","type_b","type_c","type_d","type_e","type_f","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"]), .range(["darkblue", "gray45" , "khaki4", "skyblue1", "darkgoldenrod4", "gray27", "darkblue", "gray45" , "khaki4", "skyblue1", "darkgoldenrod4", "gray27","darkgreen", "forestgreen","yellowgreen","peru"])'

Network2 <- sankeyNetwork(Links=links2, Nodes=nodes2, Source = "source", Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name", sinksRight=FALSE,fontSize= 20,iterations=0, colourScale = my_colour, LinkGroup="group", NodeGroup="group")
```
````

Answer (score 0):

You have three mistakes in the JavaScript string you're passing to `sankeyNetwork`.

1. `networkD3` uses D3v4, not D3v3... the name `d3.scale.Ordinal` is from D3v3, while the D3v4 equivalent is `d3.scaleOrdinal`
2. this bit `]), .range([` should be `]).range([`
3. you'll need to use [HTML color names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#HTML_color_names) not CSS3 names